# Option disabled on submit jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I submit my ajax form, I d like to pass option submited on disabled.

```
<form action="#" id="export">
  <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option id="val-1" value="1">Spain</option>
    <option id="val-2" value="2" disabled="disabled">France</option>
    <option id="val-3" value="3">England</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

My ajax

```
$('#export').on('submit', function(e){
            // alert( ($this).serialize() );
            $.post('save_zone.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $('.pays_added_export').append(data);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Any Ideas ? I thought about something with serialize() and a data-something on option ...

Regards

Comment: `I d like to pass option submited on disabled` Huh? I've no idea what you are asking. What exactly do you want to pass in your ajax call?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://johnzeratsky.com/articles/2007/disabled_html_form_elements_are_not_submitted

Comment: Ok I realize that I was not so clear..
I mean, when my form is submited, I want the option submited become disble ! For exemple : I submit France -> option with value france become disable ! You see ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a id for you select

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="select_option">
    <option id="val-1" value="1">Spain</option>
    <option id="val-2" value="2" disabled="disabled">France</option>
    <option id="val-3" value="3">England</option>
</select>
```

and use it

```
var a_disable = [];    
$('option:disabled', '#select_option').each(function (i, option) {                     
     a_disable[i] = $(this).val();                    
});                    

$.post('save_zone.php', $(this).serialize()+'&disables='+a_disable.join(','), function(data) {
    $('.pays_added_export').append(data);
});
```